# include navigation menu out of themes dir

Tags: silverstripe

I am using this gallery.

http://www.silverstriperesources.com/modules/silverstripe-3-gallery-plugin-module/

I need to include a navigation menu file that is inside of `themes/simple/templates/includes`.

How can i do that? The problem is that ss3Gallery folder (in root), and respectively, `GalleryPage.ss` are out of `themes/simple`.

So, this code in GalleryPage.ss  `<% include NavigationPage %>` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending `?flush=all` to your URL?

If I remember correctly (at least in SS 2.x) the order in which SilverStripe tries to find includes is:

1. mysite/templates/Includes/
2. themes/your-theme/templates/Includes/
3. your-module/templates/Includes/

So you can always override includes (or layouts).

Answer (score 0):

If SilverStripe 3 works with themes like SilverStripe 2.x, you should be able to copy the **/ss3Gallery/templates** folder to **/themes/simple_ss3Gallery/templates**. These new files will override the ones in the extension directory.